# C# WPF ListView with GridView - add/remove columns context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, contextmenu, gridviewcolumn

I'm trying to add a context menu to a ListView (using GridView) to toggle column visibility. It's a simple menu - it just has a list of all the available columns, and if the column name is checked, that column should be visible.

My ListView is displayed with a GridView. The GridViewColumnHeader for each column has a Name property and Header property that match with a ContextMenu MenuItem with the same Name and Header values. My problem is that I can't figure out how to select a GridViewColumn by its GridViewColumnHeader's name **without** iterating through all the columns.

I can select a column by index, but that won't work since the column index changes if the columns are reordered by the user.

Is there a way to select a column by header data? I'm thinking something like this:

```
MenuItem m = e.Source as MenuItem;
GridView gv = (GridView)list.View;
GridViewColumn gvc = gv.Columns[m.Name];
//code to make width 0 or Auto goes here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no built in method for this.
You can use LINQ expression:

```
var col = gv.Columns.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Header == "name");
```

but it will iterate through the columns inside. I believe iterating will be pretty fast.
The other way to avoid iterating completely is to subscribe on `CollectionChanged` event and save mapping between column header and column. But this is tricky way.

```
private Dictionary<object, GridViewColumn> _columns = new Dictionary<object, GridViewColumn>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gv.Columns.CollectionChanged += Columns_CollectionChanged;
}

private void Columns_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if((e.Action==NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove 
       || e.Action==NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
       && e.OldItems!=null)
   {
       foreach(GridViewColumn oldItem in e.OldItems)
       {
           if(_columns.ContainsKey(oldItem.Header)) _columns.Remove((oldItem.Header));
       }
   }
   if(e.NewItems!=null)
   {
       foreach(GridViewColumn newItem in e.NewItems)
       {
           _columns[newItem.Header] = newItem;
       }
   }
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
        gv.Columns.CollectionChanged -= Columns_CollectionChanged;
    }
    catch { }
}

private GridViewColumn GetColumn(string header)
{
    GridViewColumn column = null;
    _columns.TryGetValue(header, out column);
    return column;
}
```